# Javascript pattern for going back and forward on a promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I have learned to love and utilize promise chains. However sometimes I need to repeat a stage in the execution. Is there a way to do it without breaking the promise chain into separate methods?

```
dataLayer.loginUser(loginData)
    .then(function (response) {

         console.log('loginUser response -> ', response);
         return dataLayer.getData();

    }.bind(this))
    .then(function (response) {

         console.log('loginUser response -> ', response);
         if (response.message === 'JWT_EXPIRED') {
             // Somehow go back to the previous stage
             return dataLayer.refreshJWT().then(...);
         }

      // next stage
      return ...
    });
```

Comment: I don't think so. You'd need to wrap your functions in a queue for that. Even if you were to name your function handlers and reuse them later on. There's no way the handler know what was the last handler used, unless a proper list structure is used.

Comment: I would hate to debug that code if one could do what you are asking for ;) Creating a method to run the code you need to re-run sounds like a much simpler and comprehensible solution.

Comment: @JuanMendes We are used to have code that only goes forward and maybe it is the only way if we want to debug it without losing ourselves in the code. I still wonder whether there is room for code that runs in steps. I find many cases in which it would help me tremendously, especially in handling errors, as many times errors do not beed to break the chain but need to be addressed and continue with the process.

Comment: @Guy I understand what you are trying to do, I'm just saying it's not easy to follow the code when you have a state machine and you are allowed to go back and forth within that state machine willy-nilly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not. You will need a separate function that you can refer to and call again.

Of course, you can just use a named function expression as a `then` callback, so it won't "break" your chain:

```
dataLayer.loginUser(loginData)
.then(function tryToGetData(response) {
    console.log('loginUser response -> ', response);
    return dataLayer.getData().then(function (response) {
        console.log('loginUser response -> ', response);
        if (response.message === 'JWT_EXPIRED') {
            return tryToGetData(response); // again!
        return response;
    });
}).then(function(response) {
    // next stage
    return …;
});
```